# Validate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a simple form. But I keep getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
```

Here is my html file with form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cohorts</title>


  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="trunk/dev/validation.js"></script>

    <form id="register-form" class="form-horizontal" name="form" ng-submit="addCohort()">

      <div class="form-group">

        <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Name:</label>

        <input name="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="text" ng-model="formCohort.firstname">

        <input class = "btn-btn-primary" id="submit-button"  type="submit" value="Sigin up">
      </div>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my validation.

```
$(function () {
  $("#register-form").validate({
    rules:{
      email:{
        required: true,
        email: true

      }
    }
  });

});
```

Here is the error in my console:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You've included the validate library twice. Delete one of the files, I would suggest that you keep the `.min` version

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I removed it and it still gave me the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first include the jQuery library
and than your validate plugin

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="trunk/dev/validation.js"></script>
```

P.S: make sure you have only one `validate` plugin!

Additionally, I'd suggest you to include your `<script>` tags right **before** the closing `</body>` tag.

```html
<form id="register-form">
  <input name="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Sigin up">
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
  
    $("#register-form").validate({
      rules: {
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        }
      }
    });
    
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to put in the <head> but it still gave the same error:(

Comment: @user3599415 pelase see my jsBin demo, download it and open it in your favorite code editor. Compare the codes and have fun.

Comment: @user3599415 make sure you FIRST include jQuery, and only than the validate plugin. If you use a different order that you'll get the error.